# How to change an empty label to a multi-line label in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label that I want to be empty until a button is pressed that searches a csv file to find scores from entries of the same name as an entered name. Any values that are found to be displayed into a label, currently only the first values are shown by the list, thanks.

```
entSearch = Entry(window)
lblSearch = tkinter.Label(window, text="Search for your previous scores!")
btnSearch = Button(window, text="Search!",command=search)
lblSearched = tkinter.Label(window, text="")

def search():
file1=open("scores.csv","r")
csvreader=csv.reader(file1)
for x in csvreader:
    if entSearch.get() == x[0]:
        results = x[0]+" "+x[1]+"\n"
    lblSearched.config(text=results)
```

Comment: simply first create one string with all text and later put it in `Label`. Or use `lblSearched['text'] += results`

Comment: BTW: today already was similar question: [How to append text to a label using text from a file and an entry in tkinter python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462282/how-to-append-text-to-a-label-using-text-from-a-file-and-an-entry-in-tkinter-pyt)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect all in one text and later put it in `Label`

```
searched_text = entSearch.get()

full_text = ''

for row in csvreader:
    if  row[0] == searched_text:
        # with '\n'
        full_text += "{} {}\n".format(row[0], row[1])

lblSearched.config(text=full_text)
```

or with `join()` (it will not add `\n` after last line)

```
searched_text = entSearch.get()

all_lines = []

for row in csvreader:
    if  row[0] == searched_text:
        # WITHOUT '\n'
        all_lines.append("{} {}".format(row[0], row[1]))

full_text = '\n'.join(all_lines)
lblSearched.config(text=full_text)
```

In your current code you can use

```
lblSearched['text'] += results
```

or

```
lblSearched.config(text=lblSearched.cget('text') + results)
```

but it is less readable.